# Releasing only the changed modules in a multi-module project

Tags: java, git, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I stumbled upon the [Multi Module Maven Release Plugin](http://danielflower.github.io/2015/03/08/The-Multi-Module-Maven-Release-Plugin-for-Git.html)  which offers the functionality of only building *changed* modules (and everything that depends on them).

As it only works with Git (we have SVN) and I do not know whether it is stable/well tested, I wonder if this functionality is also achievable without using the plugin (or reverse engineering it).

Comment: My question to that: Why do you have a multi module build?

Comment: If I have a dependency hierarchy like A -> B -> C and I change C, it would be great to automatically build A and B as well. This seems to be most easily achieved with multi-module builds. On the other hand, if I change A, it seems strange to me to give a new version number to B and C as well.

Comment: You are aware that git can work up against a subversion repository?

Comment: Not really. But if I understood the plugin description correctly, it depends on some git feature to determine which modules have changed since the last release and I don't know if this still works correctly if we have an extra layer in between.